# UIImagePickerViewController memory warning in iphone while getting image from photolibrary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

when i run this program on iphone after adding thre to four image memory warning come and app crash. so please help me Thanks i just get image reference and write on file and then getting image from file path. Thanks

```
- (IBAction)addPicsButtonClick:(id)sender 
{
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;    
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];    
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{        
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pathToDocuments=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 0.3f);    
    [imageData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.jpg", pathToDocuments, [app.images count]] atomically:YES];    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: keep your code of addPicsButtonClick in autorelease pool may be that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code in a new app in the simulator, and had no crash problem or memory warning, and it created the files.  I did take out [app.images count] and used a local variable instead, as app.images is not set anywhere in this code.  So if that variable is trash or over-released, that might be your problem.